# Implementing the Iterable and Iterator interfaces for TreeMap in Java

Tags: java, iterator, implementation, treemap, iterable

I have an assignment where I have a TreeMap<String,Node> and I have to implement the Iterable and Iterator interfaces to support a for-loop printing all the String-keys of the map. Java and interfaces are completely new to me, and all our examples were about linked lists.

The issue seems to be in my next() function, and my code won't even compile because of a
NoSuchElementException. What's wrong with the implementation? Below are the relevant parts of my code.

```
public class OwnNode extends Node implements Iterable<String> {

    private TreeMap<String,Node> allNodes;

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return new MapIterator();
    }

    private class MapIterator implements Iterator<String> {

        Set<String> keys = allNodes.keySet();
        Iterator<String> keyIterator = keys.iterator();
        String key = keyIterator.next();

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
          return key != null
        }
        
        @Override
        public String next() {
          if( key == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No more values!");
          }
          var name = key;
          key = keyIterator.next();
          return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you aren't adding any values to `allNodes`. Maybe try to post a [mcve] even if it is code that does not compile. I may be able to fix it.

Comment: @Abra The actual adding of values is done by a bit complex code that was provided by the teacher, so the values should be added

Comment: I can't help you debug your code just by looking at a few lines of it. I need something I can actually run and debug. Besides, `NoSuchElementException` is a runtime exception which implies that your code does compile. So are you getting an exception when you run your code or does your code not compile? Is `Node` also a class that your teacher wrote?

Comment: @Abra my mistake, it does compile and the error happens when running the code. And yes it is. I just made sure that the values are actually added to the map and they are, and managed to print the first name in the map before the program crashed to the same error. Apparently the line "key = keyIterator.next();" is an issue